# Turning off ipv6 in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dns, ipv6

I am attempting to reduce network traffic.  Every time httpd on our CentOS 7 box makes a dns query, I can see that both an A and an AAAA request type hitting our internal dns server.

Since we are not planning on going to ipv6, I've tried to turn off ipv6 by adding: net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 and net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 to /etc/sysctl.conf and restarting the network service.

But we're still getting AAAA Requests on the DNS server.  Will I need to turn off ipv6 in the httpd.conf file?

Comment: Why does httpd make a dns query at all? Are you reverse resolving the client IP?

Comment: to be honest, I'm not sure why httpd is making the dns query.  I just know that httpd is the only service active on the server - and when I look up a site from the httpd server, I see the AAAA 'hit' on the dns server

Comment: So, are you using it as a proxy? In that case, we really need to know which program is running the actual httpd service: squid, nginx, apache, ...

Comment: The server is running on aws and is part of an autoscale cluster.  The httpd.conf is on an external resource mounted on the server.  /mnt/blog/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.  The conf file shows we're running apache.  I know we use nginx in other parts of our platform, but I can't see any reference to it on this server